# Rails search with will Paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Below the code I am using now.Current code pagination will show 100 users per page.Currently search functionlaity implemented using JQuery code.Since pagination showing 100 records, search only working for 100 records. I need to implement search with will paginate.If I search users,It will fetch details from database and show in table .Can anyone please suggest how implement this with will paginate in rails?

Controller

```
 @user_list = User.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 100)
```

html.erb

```
 <%= will_paginate @user_list %>
<table id="users_access_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Curernt Access</th>
    <th>API User Access</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="table_body">
  <br>
  <div class="col-md-4" style="float: left;">
    <input class="form-control" title="Search" type="text" id="userinput" onkeyup=" searchUsers()" placeholder="Search &#x1F50D; :">
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <% @user_list.each do |user| %>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <%=user['name']%>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%=user['email']%>
      </td>
       <td>
        <%=user['access']%>
      </td>
       <td>
        <%=user['api_users']%>
      </td>
      
 </td>
        
       <td>
```

Comment: I guess the `onkeyup` event is doing a client-side search operation. What you really want is to send the query to your backend, filter your data based on the params you passed and render the response. Something [like this](https://railsblogs.rohityadav.in/2017/11/searching-using-ajax-in-rails.html) should help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make changes in the controller level and UI side as well.

I am considering the parameters are coming to the controller from the UI side, and making changes in the query on the user controller.

Instead of `all` you need to create `LIKE` query

```
@user_list = User.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 100)
```

change it with

```
@user_list = User.where("name LIKE ? OR email LIKE ?", "%#{search_param}%", "%#{search_param}%").page(params[:page]).per(100)
```

hope it helps you to resolve your query.